# Python simple data working

Tags: python, scripting, physics

I am presenting my problem. I have a molecule of Benzene, I have a Cartesian coordinates for each atom. What I want is to rotate the molecule around its center of mass in z, and x direction.

For doing this, I need to calculate the center of mass M.

Within the file, the coordinates of the molecule geometry is given below (txt file).

```
         X  Y  Z
atom     4  5  7  C
atom     3  7  9  C
```

I have many more rows like this. The test file comprise of not just numbers and include data.

The question I have is, how can I go over/summarize over rows and strings in Python?  Because for center of mass, I will need to summarize X coordinate for all atoms and then divide the X coordinate by 6. And I have no idea how to do this.

I know how to choose certain row and line but I don't need certain elements. I need my program to to read lines, split them,  and choose particular sata and summarize them.

Please guide me through the next steps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you written any code to try to solve this? You should add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have written two methods of implementing the code based on the assumptions that I have made and understand what is required to be done here.

**Method 1: Program 1**

```
xcoordinatedata=[]
fileopen=open("atomdata.txt", "r+")
i=0
for rows in fileopen.readlines():
    if i==0:
        i=1
    pass
else:
    xcoordinatedata.append(float(rows.split("\t")[1])/6)

fileopen.close()
print "The X coordinate data is", xcoordinatedata
```

**Method 2 :Second method to implement the same program**

```
xcoordinatedata=[]
fileopen=open("atomdata.txt", "r+")
i=0
for row in fileopen.readlines():
    if i!=0:
        xcoordinatedata.append(float(row.split("\t")[1])/6)
        i+=1
    i=1

fileopen.close()
print "out of the program", xcoordinatedata
```

Please let me know if this helps. Please provide your code so that I can help you further.